# How to get title attribute for each a href and put as span?

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to get the title attribute of each a href in jQuery and put it as a span and have done something like this:

```
$('.menu li').each(function(){
    var title = $('.menu li a').attr("title");
    $(".menu li a span").text(title);
});
```

Each link has a different title attribute added too it but its applying the first title attribute to every span, am I missing something?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting *every* menu's `li` inside your loop. You want to affect only the `<li>` within the current `.menu`:

```
$('.menu li').each(function(){
  var title = $(this).find("a").attr("title");
  $(this).find("a span").text(title);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the matched element being iterated (a `.menu li` element) in the `each` with `this` keyword:

```
$(".menu li").each(function(){
    var title = $(this).find("a").attr("title");
    $(this).find("a span").text(title);
});
```